# BV Commerce 2017 Order Placed and Order Status Issue When Payment Method is SagePay in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, e-commerce, payment-gateway

I have created an E-commerce based web application based on VB.Net with "BV Commerce" but currently there is an issue with Order. If the order payment method is SagePay then sometimes the status and place flag don't update and I am unable to see that order in List Page in Admin.

I try to figure out on a local basis but it won't work on a local and in the live environment, there is only some order in that I am not able to see that rest are works properly. So I guess the problem here with SagePay so if anyone has an idea please let me know.